# Is it possible to delay antimalware service execution start in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

After 4 minutes of inactivity antimalware service starts running. Can this time increase?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Launch `Services.msc` and change the **Startup type** to **Automatic (Delayed Start)** for the anti-malware service.

In the registry, navigate to **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AntiMalwareServiceName** and add a registry value of type **REG_DWORD** named **AutoStartDelay** and give it a delay value in seconds

Comment: MsMpEng.exe is not listed in Services.msc but listed in task manager.

Comment: Also, I navigated to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ and did not find AntiMalwareServiceName.